# color detection using opencv

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to extract the title bar from the image below using opencv.

[image]

I am using the following code -

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat original = Imgcodecs.imread("D:/test_bg_extract.png", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Mat hsvMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(original, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    Mat dst = new Mat();
    Core.inRange(hsvMat, new Scalar(23,231,205), new Scalar(23,231,205), dst);
```

I used a color picker to determine the HSV value of the title bar (from the hsvMat converted to display image). When the run the code to display the output, I see a blank screen. I can't tell what I am doing wrong. Am I picking the wrong HSV color? If I know the exact RGB code then should I even be converting image to HSV? (this however seems to be the standard method from many code examples on the internet).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I  solved it using RGB based color, switching to BGR while specifying the color that I need. So this worked -

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat original = Imgcodecs.imread("D:/test_bg_extract.png", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Mat dst = new Mat();
    Core.inRange(original, new Scalar(132,178,205), new Scalar(132,178,205), dst);
```

Comment: I learnt that I don't have to use HSV unless I need a range. In my case, it was just a single RGB value.